# Top level view in a UIView hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a singleton instance of a custom UIView with a method `-(void)display` whose job is to animate the custom view in and out on whatever screen is currently being displayed. (kind of like the -show method in UIAlertView).

My question is how do I determine which view is at the top of the UIView hierarchy and currently displayed?

Comment: doesn't it work if retrieve yourView.subviews.lastObject, the subviews are arranged according to order inside viewObject.subview; the last subview is the topmost

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you want your custom view at the top of all subviews right? Isn't adding it as a final subview at the very end of the viewDidLoad method a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "top" of the view hierarchy is a UIWindow. And there can be (and usually is) more than one UIWindow in the application. If you want to have something shown over everything else on the screen, I suggest you implement a custom UIWindow. E.g. UIAlertView is also implemented this way.